# Ошибка при создании Artifacts Java FX Packager: Can't build artifact - fx:deploy is not available in this JDK

Tags: java, javafx

Пытаюсь научиться создать Artifacts с запускаемым exe файлом, однако столкнулся со следующей ошибкой: Java FX Packager: Can't build artifact - fx:deploy is not available in this JDK

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При создании задаю следующие параметры
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Внятного объяснения причины возникновения этой ошибки, и тем более ее решения, я не нашел.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как решить данную проблему? Спасибо!

Comment: у вас случаем не openJdk установлена?

Comment: OracleJdk + подключал библиотеки из openJFX

Comment: Получилось? А то у меня такая же проблема.

Comment: @ДмитрийЧубаров Нет, все еще в поисках решения проблемы

Answer (score 0):

Эта ошибка возникает, когда используешь java 8 и выше. Если использовать 7 и ниже, то ошибки быть не должно, но я не проверял.

Если удалось запустить программу, то значит в папке с проектом есть jar файл проекта, а его можно конвертировать в exe с помощью Launch4J (его можно вроде и в сам intellij idea добавить, но наверное проще будет установить его на компьютер и уже в его gui сделать конвертацию)

Если делать через intellij idea, тогда нужно использовать jlink и jpackage. jlink у меня работает, а вот чтобы делать разные сборки, то там jpackage нужно использовать, а он даже в официальном проекте примере не работает, пока не разобрался в чем дело...

https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs - здесь много полезной информации, а касательно вопроса нужно смотреть раздел "Runtime images"